# ASP.NET MVC Bootstrap iPhone Navigation bar UI Issue

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, asp.net-mvc-5

I've setup a new ASP.NET MVC website, using the defaults in Visual Studio 2013. I've updated all the libraries being used so that I have the latest version of bootstrap and other CSS, JavaScript and MS libraries installed.

What I've found is that if you add basic form with validation, the Bootstrap navigation bar doesn't stay on top, it falls to the middle of the screen on an iPhone. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

You'll notice the menu is the middle of the screen, instead of being on top.

To duplicate, open the URL on an iPhone just click submit which will cause the a validation error and display the UI issue.

Note, I have removed the bundling so that we can see the individual links. I also put them all in the header for convenience, not something that we would do in production.

What is the solution to anchoring the navigation bar?

Comment: maybe this could help: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/iphone-safari-address-bar-jumps-down-after-page-transition or this one: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/stopping-the-url-bar-from-dropping-down-i-discovered-a-workaround

Comment: My guess is this is related to Bootstrap, so the jQuery mobile solutions wouldn't be helpful. If it is a larger problem with iOS, it might be helpful, but I'd need to figure out the difference between jQuery mobile and Bootstrap.

Comment: Could be related to this: http://dansajin.com/2012/12/07/fix-position-fixed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of a skilled CSS programmer, I was able to resolve with the following updates:

Run the following JavaScript after bootstrap:

```
var is_ios = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false );
      if(is_ios) {
        $(document)
        .on('focus', 'input, textarea', function(e) {
            $('body').addClass('fixfixed');
        })
        .on('blur', 'input, textarea', function(e) {
            $('body').removeClass('fixfixed');
        });        
      }
```

Added the following CSS updates:

```
.form .form-control {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.fixfixed .navbar {
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
}
```